# Class code coverage is 100% but unit test file is not

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

I have a class object (*my_object*), the methods within that class are all covered by my unittesting. However the unit test file itself has some lines of codes which are *missed*. These lines of code are exception handlers.

So for example for the unit test below:

```
def test_remove_file(self):
 my_object.put_file(my_file)
  try:
     my_object.check_file_exists(my_file)
  except Exception:
     assert False
  response = my_object.remove_file(my_file)
  assert response == True
```

The coverage report says that the exception handler is missed. How can I prevent this, and what is
the implication of not covering this within the unit test?

Comment: I'd suggest excluding the tests from the coverage report, the tests are there to provide coverage to the 'real' code... including the tests themselves in the coverage stats will skew the numbers and is not helpful

Comment: A test that raises any exception (not just an `AssertionError`) is considered a failed test. There's no reason to catch one exception just to raise another.

Comment: Definitely don't exclude the tests from the coverage report: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/dont_omit_tests_from_coverage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let the exception raised by `my_object.check_file_exists` cause the failure, instead of capturing it and raising an `AssertionError` in its place.

```
def test_remove_file(self):
    my_object.put_file(my_file)
    my_object.check_file_exists(my_file)
    assert my_object.remove_file(my_file)
```

The only purpose of the `assert` statement is to convert a non-true return value from `my_object.remove_file` into an exception.

Comment: This did the trick! Makes so much sense, thanks.